One sentry transaction between microservices
How can you use one sentry transaction between microservices communicating using rabbitmq?
I tried:
Producer middleware:
public function handle(Envelope $envelope, StackInterface $stack): Envelope
{
    $transaction = SentrySdk::getCurrentHub()->getTransaction();

    if (!is_null($transaction)) {
        $spanContext = new SpanContext();
        $spanContext->setOp('rabbitmq.send');
        $spanContext->setDescription('description');

        $span = $transaction->startChild($spanContext);
        $sentryTrace = $span->toTraceparent();

        $envelope = $envelope->with(new SentryStamp($sentryTrace));

        $envelope = $stack->next()->handle($envelope, $stack);

        $span->finish();

        return $envelope;
    }

    return $stack->next()->handle($envelope, $stack);
}

Consumer Middleware:
public function handle(Envelope $envelope, StackInterface $stack): Envelope
{
    /** @var $sentryStamp SentryStamp */
    $sentryStamp = $envelope->last(SentryStamp::class);
    if (!is_null($sentryStamp)) {
        $sentryTrace = $sentryStamp->getSentryTrace();
        $transactionContext = TransactionContext::fromSentryTrace($sentryTrace);
        $transactionContext->setOp('rabbitmq.consumer');
        $transactionContext->setDescription('description');

        $transaction = SentrySdk::getCurrentHub()->startTransaction($transactionContext);
        SentrySdk::getCurrentHub()->setSpan($transaction);

        $spanContext = new SpanContext();
        $spanContext->setOp('processing');
        $spanContext->setDescription("description");
        $span = $transaction->startChild($spanContext);
        SentrySdk::getCurrentHub()->setSpan($span);

        $envelope = $stack->next()->handle($envelope, $stack);

        $span->finish();
        $transaction->finish();

        return $envelope;
    }

    return $stack->next()->handle($envelope, $stack);
}

But consumer create new transaction. Dont use current transaction. How to send transaction between 2 microservice with rabbitmq?

Dear To use a single Sentry transaction between microservices communicating with RabbitMQ, you need to properly propagate the Sentry context. that's how you can done this
Producer Middleware
Retrieve the current transaction or start a new one if none exists.
Create a child span for sending the message.
Attach the Sentry trace information to the message.
public function handle(Envelope $envelope, StackInterface $stack): Envelope
{
    $transaction = SentrySdk::getCurrentHub()->getTransaction();
    if (is_null($transaction)) {
        $transactionContext = new TransactionContext();
        $transactionContext->setName('TransactionName');
        $transaction = SentrySdk::getCurrentHub()->startTransaction($transactionContext);
    }

    $spanContext = new SpanContext();
    $spanContext->setOp('rabbitmq.send');
    $spanContext->setDescription('Sending message to RabbitMQ');
    $span = $transaction->startChild($spanContext);

    $sentryTrace = $span->toTraceparent();
    $envelope = $envelope->with(new SentryStamp($sentryTrace));

    $envelope = $stack->next()->handle($envelope, $stack);

    $span->finish();

    return $envelope;
}

Consumer Middleware
Extract the Sentry trace from the message.
Start a new transaction using the extracted trace.
Create a child span for processing the message.
public function handle(Envelope $envelope, StackInterface $stack): Envelope
{
    $sentryStamp = $envelope->last(SentryStamp::class);

    if (!is_null($sentryStamp)) {
        $sentryTrace = $sentryStamp->getSentryTrace();
        $transactionContext = TransactionContext::fromSentryTrace($sentryTrace);
        $transactionContext->setOp('rabbitmq.consumer');
        $transactionContext->setDescription('Consuming message from RabbitMQ');

        $transaction = SentrySdk::getCurrentHub()->startTransaction($transactionContext);
        SentrySdk::getCurrentHub()->setSpan($transaction);

        $spanContext = new SpanContext();
        $spanContext->setOp('processing');
        $spanContext->setDescription('Processing message');
        $span = $transaction->startChild($spanContext);

        $envelope = $stack->next()->handle($envelope, $stack);

        $span->finish();
        $transaction->finish();

        return $envelope;
    }

    return $stack->next()->handle($envelope, $stack);
}

